# Flutter lifting the state up through multiple dynamically added widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget, flutter-state

I'm trying to build a parent widget that has a button, when clicked, it displays another widget with some text and a drop-down list. When the drop-down selection is changed, the text should change accordingly. I've included below a simplified code of what I'm trying to achieve which doesn't work. The state lifting up concept is something confusing for me as a newcomer to Flutter

[image: screen]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String text = "Empty";

  void addWidget() {
    setState(() {
      widList.clear();
      widList.add(MidWidget(
        text: text,
        setValue: selectValue,
      ));
    });
  }

  void selectValue(String value) {
    setState(() {
  text = value;
});
  }

  List<Widget> widList = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(children: [
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: addWidget, child: const Text("Add Widget")),
          Column(
            children: widList,
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MidWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MidWidget({super.key, required this.text, required this.setValue});
  final String text;
  final Function setValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(text),
        LowestWidget(
          dropDownValue: "First",
          setValue: setValue,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

////////////////////
///////////////////
///

class LowestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  LowestWidget(
      {super.key, required this.dropDownValue, required this.setValue});

  final List<String> items = ["First", "Second"];
  final String dropDownValue;
  final Function setValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropDownValue,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      onChanged: (String? value) {
        setValue(value);
      },
      items: items.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, both `MidWidget` and `LowestWidget` need to be converted to `StatefulWidget` because we need state changes inside those widgets too.

Secondly, `selectValue` function should be in the `MidWidget`, not in the parent widget, because it attempts to change the state of `text` that has already been passed onto the `MidWidget` with its original value at the time of its instantiation. Any change in `text` via `setState` is not going to affect its value in `MidWidget` anymore.

Thirdly, I've introduced `_value` variable in both `MidWidget` and `LowestWidget` that takes its initial value from the respective parent widgets in `initState` and then gets value changes via `setState` that are then used to be displayed in `Text` widget in `MidWidget` and `DropdownButton` widget in `LowestWidget`.

Following is the revised code that is working as per your requirements. I've commented out the deletions so that you could relate it with the original code.

Hope it helps!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String text = "Empty";

  void addWidget() {
    setState(() {
      widList.clear();
      widList.add(MidWidget(
        text: text,
        // setValue: selectValue,
      ));
    });
  }

  // void selectValue(String value) {
  //   setState(() {
  //     text = value;
  //   });
  // }

  List<Widget> widList = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(children: [
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: addWidget, child: const Text("Add Widget")),
          Column(
            children: widList,
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MidWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MidWidget({super.key, required this.text, /*required this.setValue*/});
  final String text;
  // final Function setValue;

  @override
  State<MidWidget> createState() => _MidWidgetState();
}

class _MidWidgetState extends State<MidWidget> {
  String? _value;

  void selectValue(String value) {
    setState(() => _value = value);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _value = widget.text;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(_value!),
        LowestWidget(
          dropDownValue: "First",
          setValue: selectValue,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

////////////////////
///////////////////
///

class LowestWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  LowestWidget(
      {super.key, required this.dropDownValue, required this.setValue});

  final String dropDownValue;
  final Function setValue;

  @override
  State<LowestWidget> createState() => _LowestWidgetState();
}

class _LowestWidgetState extends State<LowestWidget> {
  final List<String> items = ["First", "Second"];

  String? _value;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _value = widget.dropDownValue;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: _value,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      onChanged: (String? value) {
        setState(() => _value = value);
        widget.setValue(value);
      },
      items: items.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed the mid one to stateful and let the bottom one as stateless, and using callbacks it looks ok so far